# Using logistic regression model results with independent variable value that is outside of the range in the training data set

Tags: regression, logistic, extrapolation

For a small school project, I have applied a simple binary logistic model (using glm() in r) to predict the probability of passing a test based on these independent variables - the person's age, gender and the year they are taking the test.

The model was fitted on past individual test results (pass or fail) with the above independent variables. I am not sure if I would violate any assumptions of logistic regression if I want to estimate the person's probability of passing the test in the future, e.g. if a female, aged 25, taking the test in 2021. Because the independent integer variable, *2021*, is not actually in the observations used to fit the model.

If I assume trend observed across the past years will continue, then it is reasonable to use the fitted model?